# QScrollArea doesn't work in my custom widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to use qt , and my first app is to design simple UI , the UI must have a custom widget( a label and a qsliser and a spin )to control my video app , so i write something like this

```
class Controls : public QWidget
{


private:

    QHBoxLayout *Layout ;
    string Controlname;
    QLabel *Label ;

    QSpinBox *Spin ;



public:

    QSlider *Slider ;
    Controls(QLayout &Parent , string name , const int &Default_value);
    Controls(const Controls &copy);
    explicit Controls();
    ~Controls(){}


    QLabel * Get_Label() const { return Label ; }
    QSlider *Get_Slider() const { return Slider ; }
    QSpinBox *  Get_Spin()const  { return Spin ; }
    QHBoxLayout *  Get_Layout() {return Layout;}

    void SetValue(const int &newvalue);

    Controls &operator= (const Controls &copy);


};
```

and to create an object from this widget i do it like this:

```
QVBoxLayout layout ;
 Controls *gg   =new Controls (layout ,  "test", 1);
 Controls *gg2   =new Controls (layout ,  "test2", 4);
```

now i am want to create this object inside qsliderarea so i do this

```
QScrollArea gt ;
 gt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
 gt.setWidget(gg);
 gt.setWidget(gg2);
 gt.show();
```

but when i run my app i see the sliderarea but no control inside it ; what is the problem in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a parent widget which contains the layout which shall contain the controls. Also you shouldn't create the layout on the stack, as it would be deleted the moment the method which creates it returns.

Something along these lines:

```
// It is not sufficient to set the layout as a parent, you need to add the 
// widgets to the layout. Note that this won't compile unless you change your
// constructor to accept a QLayout* instead of a QLayout&.
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget( new Controls( layout, "test1", 1 );
layout->addWidget( new Controls( layout, "test2", 4 );

// A parent widget 'scrollWidget' is required which contains the layout.
QWidget* scrollWidget = new QWidget( /* maybe assign a parent here
    so you don't have to worry about deletion */ );
scrollWidget->setLayout( layout );

// Your scrollArea can now include that 'scrollWidget' which itself contains 
// everything else.
QScrollArea* scrollArea;
scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn );
scrollArea->setWidget( scrollWidget );
scrollArea.show();   // Note it is more common to have the scroll area as part of
                     // another widget and show that instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of strange things. Those `const int &` has no sense, your constructors doesn't reflect Qt standard of coding.
Assign operator for QWidget is very big WTF, there is reason why all QObjects have private assign operators.
Seeing this strange things I suspect that underneath there is much more problems with your code and bug with QScrollArea is just manifestation of those problems.

There are two ways how scroll area can control size of child widget. The widget itself has layout set (this is what you need), or sizeHint is properly implemented.